# What is a good reference for an elliptic curve over a local field having a semi-stable Neron model over a field extension of degree $\le6$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, neron-model

Im reading Mazur's Proof of his famous theorem for the torsion of elliptic curves. He points to a result that given an elliptic curve over a given local field, there is a field extension of ramification degree not bigger than 6, over which the given curve has at least multiplicative type reduction. He cites a paper as reference for this fact (https://wstein.org/papers/bib/Serre-Tate-Good_Reduction_of_Abelian_Varieties.pdf) but I don't seem to find said result in it. Any idea where I can learn more about it?[image]

Comment: Please try to make your titles more specific - "what is a good reference for this result" could mean literally anything. I've made an attempt at making your title reflect the content of your question a bit better - please feel free to improve your title further if I haven't gotten it quite where you'd like it.